# How is privacy achieved here?

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me how the public and private methods are achiveved in this example code for a simple animation library from dustin Diaz. How are the private methods distinguished from the public one?

http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-animate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just privacy by convention - he's put an underscore before the method name, which is his way of saying "this method is private, don't call it".

Comment: Right. I thought that might be the case because I couldn't see any way there could be privacy. Just wanted to me make sure there wasn't something I was missing

Answer (score 3):

It isn't; there is no visibility in Javascript aside from scope.  Those specifications in the example are based off of method nomenclature and purpose only.

Answer (score 3):

In short:

Summary

- private variables are declared with the `var` keyword inside the object, and can only be accessed by private functions and privileged methods.
- private functions are declared inline inside the object's constructor (or alternatively may be defined via `var functionName=function(){...}`) and may only be called by privileged methods (including the object's constructor).
- privileged methods are declared with `this.methodName=function(){...}` and may invoked by code external to the object.
- public properties are declared with `this.variableName` and may be read/written from outside the object.
- public methods are defined by `Classname.prototype.methodName = function(){...}` and may be called from outside the object.
- `prototype` properties are defined by `Classname.prototype.propertyName = someValue`
- static properties are defined by `Classname.propertyName = someValue`

You can read an excellent article here:

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: That's how privacy can be achieved, but it doesn't explain what's going on here.

Comment: Could you edit that so I can read the whole thing and provide a citation?